# Backbone js: check value of get method

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

How do I check the value of what `get()` is returning?

For example, can I do this (assuming a model has been defined already):

```
var someModel = new MyModel();

if (someModel.get('title') === 'sample number one') {
    this.$el.html(_.template($('#template-one').html());
}

if (someModel.get('title') === 'sample number two') {
    this.$el.html(_.template($('#template-two').html());
}
```

or is there a better way of doing it?

Also if possible, I can I do it with a `switch(myVar){ ... }`?

Many thanks

Comment: `someModel.get(attributeName)` this is how `get` is indented to be used: you supply the attribute name; you get its value. the control flow style is a matter of taste.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @ErikAhlswede, what I'm trying to do is to render templates depending on the value of what `get()` is returning, i.e. if value of `get('title')` is 'sample number one` then use `sampleTemplateOne.html` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen to 'change' event on model and then switch template and run re-render on view.

```
var someModel = new MyModel();

someModel.on('change', this.onModelChange);

.........

onModelChange: function(model){
    if (model.get('title') === 'sample number one') {
        this.template = _.template($('#template-one'));
    }

    if (model.get('title') === 'sample number two') {
        this.template = _.template($('#template-two'));
    }

    this.render();
}
```